# Eclipse PlugIn Perspective has error "Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for PrintStream"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse 3.7, trying to build my first RCP program.
when I active the plugin perspective I have the following error 5 times:

```
Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for PrintStream [in PrintStream.class [in java.io [in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]]]
```

The Call Stack:

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for PrintStream [in PrintStream.class [in java.io [in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]]] ]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getURLContents(JavaElement.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getJavadocContents(BinaryType.java:1037)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryMethod.getAttachedJavadoc(BinaryMethod.java:643)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ProposalInfo.extractJavadoc(ProposalInfo.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ProposalInfo.computeInfo(ProposalInfo.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ProposalInfo.getInfo(ProposalInfo.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.getAdditionalProposalInfo(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:555)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.AdditionalInfoController$3.run(AdditionalInfoController.java:106)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently same problem is also described in:
[Eclipse times out when trying to show Javadoc for classes in rt.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934538/eclipse-times-out-when-trying-to-show-javadoc-for-classes-in-rt-jar)

The solution to your problem might be similar; Eclipse is looking at probably the wrong JDK installation.
Try to add a reference to your local JDK in **Preferences > Java > Installed JREs** and removing the reference to your JRE.

Comment: Did it, and re-did it didn't help. although by the error it still looks for the JRE for some reason

Comment: apparently removing all java installation and re-installing only the JDK, than resetting the eclipse to the installed JDK solved the problem. thanks